# Compare different items in different arrays

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I have a `foreach` syntax which generates following outcome:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'value' => string '2012-05-09T12:00:00' (length=19)
      'value2' => string '2012-05-09T15:00:00' (length=19)
      'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'timezone_db' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      'date_type' => string 'date' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array
      'value' => string '2012-03-14T13:00:00' (length=19)
      'value2' => string '2012-03-14T16:00:00' (length=19)
      'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'timezone_db' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      'date_type' => string 'date' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array
      ...
array
  0 => 
    array
      'value' => string '2012-02-08T13:00:00' (length=19)
      'value2' => string '2012-02-08T16:00:00' (length=19)
      'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'timezone_db' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      'date_type' => string 'date' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array
      'value' => string '2012-03-14T13:00:00' (length=19)
      'value2' => string '2012-03-14T16:00:00' (length=19)
      'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'timezone_db' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      'date_type' => string 'date' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array
      ...
```

The `...` represent a lot more code, all with the same structure.

And here is the `php` code:

```
foreach ($result as $term) {
   $node = node_load($term->nid);
   $dates = $node->field_date['und'];
   var_dump($dates);
}
```

Goal is to compare the results and check them for any inequalities. So what I'm aiming for is a script which allows me to compare `$dates[0]['value']` from the first array and `$dates[0]['value']` from the second array...

I was thinking of composing new arrays with all the `0` items or all the `1` items and later on check them, but so far no luck. Does anybody have another idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array[] = array(
    'value'       => '2012-03-14T13:00:00',
    'value2'      => '2012-03-14T16:00:00',     // <--- Error
    'timezone'    => 'Europe/Paris',
    'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
    'date_type'   => 'date',
);
$array[] = array(
    'value'       => '2012-03-14T13:00:00a',     // <--- Error
    'value2'      => '2012-03-14T16:00:00', 
    'timezone'    => 'Europe/Paris',
    'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
    'date_type'   => 'date',
);
$array[] = array(
    'value'       => '2012-03-14T13:00:00',
    'value2'      => '2012-03-14T16:00:00tt',    // <--- Error
    'timezone'    => 'Europe/Paris',
    'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
    'date_type'   => 'date11',
);

$errors = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($array)-1; $i++ ) 
    $errors = array_merge( array_diff_assoc($array[$i], $array[$i+1]) );

var_dump($errors);  

/* Output
 * ------
 * Array
 * (
 *     [value] => 2012-03-14T13:00:00a
 *     [value2] => 2012-03-14T16:00:00
 *     [date_type] => date
 * )
 */
```

Comment: Thank you for the patience and persistence during the process of solving this riddle :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array();

$array[] = array(
    'value'       => '2012-03-14T13:00:00',
    'value2'      => '2012-03-14T16:00:00',
    'timezone'    => 'Europe/Paris',
    'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
    'date_type'   => 'date',
);
$array[] = array(
    'value'       => '2012-03-14T13:00:00',
    'value2'      => '2012-03-14T16:00:00dddd',      // <--- Error is here
    'timezone'    => 'Europe/Paris',
    'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
    'date_type'   => 'date',
);
$array[] = array(
    'value'       => '2012-03-14T13:00:00',
    'value2'      => '2012-03-14T16:00:00',
    'timezone'    => 'Europe/Paris',
    'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
    'date_type'   => 'date',
);

if( count($array) > 1 )
{
    $error = false;
    $keyCount = count($array);

    for($i=0; $i < $keyCount-1; $i++)
    {
        foreach( $array[$i] as $key=>$val )
        {
            if( $array[$i+1][$key] != $val ) 
            {
                $error = $key;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

if( $error )
    echo "Error key = " . $error;
else
    echo "No errors";
```

Output: `Error key = value2`

Edit: Changes to reflect new understanding of the question.

Comment: Thanks! But I have a undefined number of arrays... So there could be one, but their could be 5 of even 6...

Comment: You will have to have a nested foreach loop, I missed that bit. But It would be more efficient that creating a new array, then running it through a foreach anyway.

Comment: Yep, that's the thing I'm not sure about, hence the question :)

Comment: Actually, if you put all your dumps into an array, Then you can nest it again, and run if( count($array[0]) == 1 ) break;

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of info and very few words... Could you update your answer maybe? :)

Comment: @Michiel yep I was on it, hows that look?

Comment: Your second edit is a close one. I'm checking it right now... But still working out the kinks.

Comment: What is you goal of this script? To check `array[1]['value']` and `array[1]['value2']` or to check `array[1]['value']` and `array[2]['value']`?

Comment: ($array[$i+1][$key] != $val) = ($array[$i+1][$key] != $array[$i][$key]) = ($array[1][$key] != $array[0][$key])

Comment: Are you referring to the answer how it is now? I won't be making any more changes now. I debugged earlier. So the output is false it all the arrays are the same, or the array key or the offending array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8788/discussion-between-bradley-forster-and-michiel)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a way

```
$array1 = array('marko','aca','milos');
$array2 = array('nemanja','marko','milos');
for($i=0;$i<count($array2);$i++)//count any array
{
if($array1[$i]!=$array2[$i])
{
    echo "Error in ".$i." <br/>";/*it will show you a number of part of array wich don't match */
}
}
```

this will give 
Error in 0 
 
Error in 1

Comment: Thanks, but same comment as the other answer. I have an undefined number of arrays. So maybe there are 3 arrays, another time there will be 5 arrays,...

Comment: I think that this way you will have what you need. Just put your arrays instead of mine,and in if loop compare $array1[$i]['value'] with array2[$i]['value'] instead of mine.

Comment: you could count main array(parent array of all arrays. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Ok, and what if I have 6 arrays?

Comment: I'll try something and if I find result I'll write back

Comment: what if you put your parent array in another array? You'll have two same arrays. Then reverse one and compare them. Can that help?